# Spring MVC HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error, Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets

When i run it on tomcat server it returns the following error in console

> SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/beans/factory/config/EmbeddedValueResolver    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:634)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:518)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Aug 13, 2017 11:50:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [dispatcher]
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/beans/factory/config/EmbeddedValueResolver    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:634)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:518)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

**HelloWorldController.Java file**

```
            package org.praveen.controller;

            import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
            import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

            @Controller
            public class HelloWorldController {
                @RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
                public String sayHello(ModelMap model) {
                    model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome From Sprng MVC");
                    return "welcome";
                }

                @RequestMapping(value="/helloAgain", method= RequestMethod.GET)

                public String sayHelloAgain(ModelMap model) {
                    model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome Again From Sprng MVC");
                    return "welcome";
                }


            }

        **spring-servlet.xml file**

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="org.praveen.controller"/>
        <mvc:annotation-driven/>

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>

        <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>


        </bean>

        </beans>

    **web.xml file**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
      <display-name>FirstSuccess</display-name>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>


    <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

   **pom.xml file**

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.praveensuccess</groupId>
  <artifactId>FirstSuccess</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
<!--   <properties> -->
<!--  <springframework.version>4.3.10.RELEASE</springframework.version> -->
<!-- </properties> -->
<dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>

</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>

</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project> 


    </web-app>
```

Comment: you are declaring dependendies to different spring arrifacts with different versions. Try making the versions match.

Comment: It worked, thanks dude..

Comment: added as an answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is that you are including spring libraries from different versions. As a rule of thumb this should not be done or these kind lf scenarios are easy to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the xmlns and xds includes in your Dispatcher servlet. Check the versions. This is the inclusions which work fine on my system.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"> </beans>
```